# wc-ajax=get_variation slow speed in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have an website. i am using WooCommerce plugin. I have added the product with variation.

When i add the product in cart by ajax it take too much time.

Please help me to resolve this.

I checked the console. it will show `"wc-ajax=get_variation"` this will take too much time.

Comment: hi please check url: https://www.webnots.com/fix-slow-page-loading-with-woocommerce-wc-ajaxget_refreshed_fragments/

Comment: I already check this and i tried. but  my ajax  call contain wc-ajax=get_variation. The recommended link work for wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments.

Comment: Can you please share your site URL so, I can check and share my thoughts over it.